# how to open ViewController in xib file

Tags: ios, swift, xib, viewcontroller

I want into xib file call these lines for opening a viewcontroller :
let myViewController = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil)

self.navigationController!.pushViewController(MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil), animated: true

Comment: What is your question? Can you explain what is happening when you are doing this? Also, provide more code. You can load a view controller sub class from a nub by using `MyViewController()` as long as the nub is also called MyViewController.xib.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate a view controller with a nib with the following line

```
let myViewController = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil)
```

If your view controller (and its nib) is inside another bundle, you also need to specify the bundle:

```
guard let bundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.company.App") else {
    return
}
let myViewController = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: bundle)
```

Also make sure that your nib is named correctly and your view controller is set as the file owner of the nib.